# Mailchimp - WordPress RSS Feed Not Valid

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, rss, mailchimp

When trying to create an RSS-driven campaign in Mailchimp, I get the  error below. My RSS link is https://www.hackisition.com/feed/.

```
https://www.hackisition.com/feed/ is not a valid RSS feed.
```

The link seems to work in my browser and a green padlock appears. I think this is due to SSL. [If I try to validate my RSS feed](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hackisition.com%2Ffeed%2F), here is what happens:

```
Server returned [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error [help]
```

How can I fix that? I'm using Nginx on the Server.

**EDIT**: It seems that CloudFlare is the problem. [See one solution here](https://jamiegoodwin.uk/how-to-use-mailchimp-rss-campaigns-with-cloudflare-flexible-ssl/).